# What to do if a user asks the same question twice?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Today I saw a user asked the same question twice.  First [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299455/printing-android-java-arraylist-to-listview) was posted.  It received a couple of down-votes, then 12 minutes later, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304516/creating-android-arraylist-error) was posted.  The questions are nearly identical. The user is asking for help on the same programming issue.

This is clearly not a major offense, but it does create some clutter in the system.  It seems it might be appropriate for one of the 2 questions to be deleted.

Is there someway to flag this situation?

Comment: You have 3k rep, vote to close as a duplicate, if you think they are... there's no need to flag it.

Comment: I don't know Java, is this actually the same question, or have they resolved an issue in the first Q and now asking for more help in the second Q - albeit the same code?

Comment: @Ben - I did vote to close it as a dup.  That is probably good enough.

Comment: Dupe them. And if they're bad questions, downvote them. People who re-ask like this are abusing the system and downvoting helps feed the question-ban algorithm.

Comment: Nice. I just saw a user who quite literally has asked a dozen questions two or more times. But I did Other-flag him to ask for mod intervention. His bad tagging prevents my dupe-hammer.

Comment: They look like different questions to me, although about the same data structure. The first question was asking how to add Animal references to the list, and the solution was to declare it as an `ArrayList<Animal>`. The second question already incorporates that change, and is about printing the list.

Comment: @Mysticial You can only dupe them if they have an upvoted answer. For poor questions posted 12 minutes apart this is by no means guaranteed.

Comment: @MartinSmith There's an exception to that rule if the questions came from the same OP. It exists specifically for this case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vote to close / flag one as a duplicate of the other. If it has a negative score, it will be cleaned up by the roomba.

I would also leave a comment asking the user not to do this. Since we aren't a traditional forum (and not a forum at all), many users aren't aware they shouldn't post the same thing twice.

Comment: This is probably good enough, although I was hoping for slightly better way.  In order to close the question, several (4?) users have to mark it as a dup.  It was clear to me, because I spent time answering the question, although no one else seemed to notice.

Comment: Interestingly, I see now that one of the questions is closed, but it was flagged as a dup mostly by people on this meta thread.

Comment: @EJK Gold-tag badge holders can dupe-hammer these questions.

Comment: @EJK That's the meta effect for ya.

Comment: Also, it takes 5 users (4 + you) to close. It *does* go into the review queue, so people will see it, even if not right away.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Thats seriously what we usually call it :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=roomba

Comment: Note that if it gets an answer, the roomba won't clear it even with a negative score (on either or both posts) - so it needs to be done promptly before people try for the 'quick internet points'.

Comment: The two questions are different. It does look as though the user is trying to learn Andriod programming by a combination of guesswork and SO questions rather than by following tutorials etc.

Comment: What if I don't have 3K reputation yet? This https://stackoverflow.com/q/52637719/3995261 is a "repost" of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52627000/3995261 ; I've downvoted the repost and left a comment, but I'm not sure whether or not to flag it "in need of moderator intervention" (duplicate's description doesn't fit, since the initial question doesn't have accepted answers yet)

Comment: @YakovL I believe that you are supposed to leave that alone (apart from DV/comment) the though behind not closing being that since the original doesn't have an answer, closing the duplicate doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I hope this is the right place to ask this, it seems relevant to this post/question. I recently asked a question and it was closed because it needed to be more focussed. In the notification of this it said I should edit it or ‘post a new one’. So I deleted my question and posted the same question again, but better, more focussed. Now my old question, which got downvoted, it in my ‘deleted questions’ list. I am trying to improve everything and edit deleted posts to make them better posts. What should I now do with this old deleted question, which is factly a duplicate of the same new question?

Comment: @SilvanSoeters unfortunately there's nothing you can do there. The system gave you poor advice.

Comment: @KevinB, that’s a shame. Thank you for letting me know. I will act differently in the future i.e. edit the post.