# What happens when the same user asks the same question twice?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

So as a new user, I've posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76585396/22152755) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76466250/22152755), and later (a few minutes after) I found that the same user who asked the first question has asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76468897/22152755) and that question got a great answer by a greater user. So now what should I do? I feel like both answers are duplicates if not *quite typical*. I don't know what's the correct practice for such situations, should I remove my answer? I have spent a fair amount of time figuring out the question and writing the answer so I feel this would be a waste.

I feel my question is not a duplicate of [What to do if a user asks the same question twice?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278510) because I don't have 3000 reputation points, and neither of those posts has a negative score, so neither will be cleaned up by the roomba. So as a "new user", what should I do?

Comment: If you find a user has submitted multiple instances of the same question, answer the original question, and flag to close any additional duplicates. You can also downvote questions, that are duplicates, of questions that were closed by the same user.

Comment: Also, if the question is really the same, a mod can merge the questions and thus move existing answers to the other question,

Comment: Ideally both of the questions should get closed as a duplicate of (the answer on the other question even links this): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573637/how-can-i-get-html-element-value-by-javascript (Not casting that close vote due to strike)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you can't [vote to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) questions, you can [flag to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the new question as a duplicate of the old question.

If both posts have good answers, you might want to flag as *'in need of moderator intervention'* and describe the situation, so they can [merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158066/1377755) the questions.

If they're reasking the question to circumvent a closure or otherwise abuse the system (which does not seem to be the case here), you still should raise a custom flag describing the situation.